# Type cast in for-each loop

Tags: loops, generics, kotlin, iterator

I'm refactoring some code and as an intermediate step I want to iterate over a list of `X` and type cast each element to `Y`. 
The following works:

```
val xs: List<X>
for (x in xs) {
    val y = x as Y
}
```

But I'd like to know how to combine the iteration and type casting so that 
1) I don't have to introduce the variable `x` and 
2) I can combine the two lines into one line.

I have tried the following

```
val xs: List<X>
for ((y as Y) in xs) {
}

val xs: List<X>
for ((y in xs) as Y) {
}
```

without any success. 
Is it even possible to combine the type cast and iteration? How?

Comment: Have you tried using the [map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) function? You could map each element to its cast form and iterate through the mapped collection. I can not try it right now but something like this: `for(y in xs.map{it as Y})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining the iteration and type casting into one line:

```
val xs: List<X>

xs.forEach { it as Y
    // Perform stuff on it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like this:

```
xs.map {it as Y}.forEach { 
            //do your stuff
        }
```

I'd say it's quite a nice syntax, without the need for any additional variables

Comment: Using `Iterable<T>#map` leads to the creation of a new collection. So it can adversely affect performance if `xs` consists of a large number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `forEach` with casting to a higher-order function:

```
inline fun <reified T> forEachCasted(iterable: Iterable<*>, action: (T) -> Unit) =
    iterable.forEach { action(it as T) }
```

And use it like this:

```
forEachCasted<Y>(xs) { ... }
```

---

Alternatively, you can make `forEachCasted` to be an extension function:

```
inline fun <reified T> Iterable<*>.forEachCasted(action: (T) -> Unit) =
    forEach { action(it as T) }
```

And use it this way:

```
xs.forEachCasted<Y> { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, using the [is operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#is-and-is-operators):

```kotlin
for (y in xs) {
    if (y is Y) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be:

```
val xs: List<X>

for (y in xs as List<Y>) {
  //use y which is a Y
}
```